# Как адаптировать разметку под устройства с челкой?

Tags: android, android-layout, разметка

Как адаптировать разметку под устройства с челкой.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/nameless1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="invest"
        android:text="@string/textView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:hint="@string/editText"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:autofillHints="" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="buy_1"
        android:text="@string/textView2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:hint="@string/editText2"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:autofillHints="" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="coin"
        android:text="@string/textView3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/editText3"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:autofillHints="" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="sell_2"
        android:text="@string/textView4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/editText4"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:autofillHints="" tools:targetApi="o" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="24"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="24"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="999999999.0000000 - ИТ.Ч   " />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/nameless01"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/nameless02"
            android:onClick="onClick2"
            android:text="@string/button2"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/nameless03"
            android:onClick="m"
            android:text="@string/button3"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/nameless04"
            android:onClick="onClick1"
            android:text="@string/button4"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/nameless05"
            android:onClick="c"
            android:text="@string/button5"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/nameless06"
            android:onClick="sum"
            android:text="@string/button6"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

Comment: Не нужно ставить метки ява и андроид студио. Вопрос не относится ни к тому, ни к другому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` в `LinearLayout`.

Если интересны другие способы, то [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/funcorp/blog/419109/) написано подробнее.

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  - ничего не меняется ,что с ним что без него.

Comment: А не всё заработало просто не с первого раза. (видно какой-то глюк был)

Comment: Да и лучше написать в MANIFEST  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />